# bash scripting tmux, multiple detach/attach

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a process I want to monitor by tail -f on several output files in different directories.   I can use a bash script start tmux as a detached session, create multiple panes, change to the top directory and reattach.  This all works.   My problem comes when I want the script to send more commands later.  Is there some reason why once I attach, my script can't send commands or detach/reattach later?   The reason to do more commands is that some files take 45 seconds to be created before I can tail them.

My example looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
# this depends on some settings from my ~/.tmux.conf

TopLevel='/tsload'
SimDir=`ls -d $TopLevel/SIM_ISS*`

# create and detach session
tmux new-session -s simwatch -n Sim_Watch -d

# make left & right panes, only 1 window
tmux split-window -h -t simwatch


# change to toplevel dir
tmux send-keys -t simwatch:1.1 "cd $SimDir" C-m
tmux send-keys -t simwatch:1.2 "cd $SimDir" C-m

tmux attach -t simwatch
```

At this point my script fails when I try to have it do more.   I've also tried 'tmux detach -t simwatch'  issue commands and reattach but they don't take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Not very familiar with tmux, but from my experiment with your script, it looks like that tmux 'attach -t simwatch' is a blocking operation, i.e. it starts and will end once you detach/exit from the session, which is when the script will continue.

Regarding the issue with the files that appear later, if you know their paths, you can try to follow them with "tail -F", which will wait for the files to appear.

```
tail --follow=name --retry missing_file
```

Comment: I didn't know about tail -F.  Thanks for that.  It will help

Comment: This is the correct answer. `tmux attach` is a blocking command. Once invoked the commands in your script won't execute further.